# JS : Stop and restart scrolling

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-waypoints

before asking the question, here is the link to a jsfiddle to understand it:
https://jsfiddle.net/yucca/87zc691c/20/

I would like to have a sequence of full screen elements with texts below each. I would like that when we scroll, if a full screen element (in gray) appears more than 25% of the height of the viewport, then we focus on it (I use waypoint). Then we can scroll on the text below. Everything goes well when you scroll slowly. But if we go quickly then all stuttering.  If the user scrolls quickly, it would be necessary to force the wait for the end of the animation then allow the user to continue scrolling normally. Can you help me to solve this problem ?

```
var $things = $('.sectionFP');

$things.waypoint(function(direction) {
      if (direction === 'down') {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 500);
      }
    }, {
      offset: '75%'
    });

$things.waypoint(function(direction) {
      if (direction === 'up') {
        var laHauteurDuViewPort = $(window).height();
        var laPositionDeLelement = $(this).offset().top;
        var laHauteurDun100VH = $('#section0').height();
        var laDifference = laPositionDeLelement - laHauteurDuViewPort;
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: laPositionDeLelement - laHauteurDuViewPort
        }, 500);
      }
    }, {
      offset: '25%'
    });
```